# Random generate 1 character a random amount of times

Tags: c#

Hi im trying to make it so I can generate a random number 1-35 so for example if the number is 25 it will write out in a string 25 equal signs. How can I do that?

```
Random r = new Random();
r.next(1, 35);
R's result = 25
string result = 25 equal signs
```

Comment: You can try with `new string('=', r.Next(1, 35))` but really I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: Make this an answer, @AlessandroD'Andria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class `string` has a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) that can do the work for you.

```
Random r = new Random();
int number = r.next(1, 35);
string result = new string('=', number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also that it should be `r.Next()` not `r.next()`.

```
Random r = new Random();
int occurrences = r.Next(1, 35);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < occurrences; i++)
{
     sb.Append('=');
}

string output = sb.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a loop to repeat adding `=` to your result.
Update your code to

```
Random r = new Random();
int total = r.next(1, 35);
string result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    result += "=";
}
```